# Long string (18Kb) response from CLI command - causes exec() to return empty string

Tags: php, exec

I'm having a hell of a headache from this issue. Seemingly easy thing - yet I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  I have a small C++ daemon listening on 127.0.0.1:3454 for requests and returning list of words separated by semicolons.

I'm trying to feed that daemon requests from PHP - but what I've encountered is - if daemon returns large string - PHP get's 0-length string instead.... I don't get it....

```
// Doesn't work - empty string is returned...
$cmd = 'printf "ends a" | nc 127.0.0.1 3454';
exec($cmd, $out);
echo 'result is: ' . (empty($out) ? '' : $out[0]);

// Works - but why the should I use a file as an intermediary..?
$cmd = 'printf "ends a" | nc 127.0.0.1 3454 > /tmp/test.txt';
exec($cmd);
$res = file_get_contents('/tmp/test.txt');
echo 'result is: ' . $res;
```

Moreover - same command: `printf "ends a" | nc 127.0.0.1 3454` - works from CLI just fine...

P.S. So in the example above daemon returns 18645 chars -> PHP get's empty string. But when it returns shorter responses - PHP get's them just fine....? why? 18645 characters is not much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a more I/O oriented function like popen

```
$read="";
$handle = popen('printf "ends a" | nc 127.0.0.1 3454');
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $read .= fread($handle, 1024);
}
echo $read;
pclose($handle);
```

**edit:**
add a loop on read

Comment: wow. yeah... - that worked! now - why the hell wasn't it working with exec? Thank you !!!

Comment: Is there any \n in your output? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php the *output* section

Comment: It seems that exec needs "lines", aka strings terminated by \n, \r or \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of functions similar to exec (system, passthru, shell_exec) or compress the data before returning it to exec.